# linq Group By and take first and lats records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I am dealing with probably simple yet difficult problem for me.
I am taking photos of parked cars and save them by car's plate and timestamp it. Same car could be photographed several times during the day.

Sample Data

| Plate | Brand | Model | InsertDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99AA111 | Tesla | S | 2022-01-17 04:00:00 |
| 99AA111 | Tesla | S | 2022-01-17 04:30:00 |
| 99AA111 | Tesla | S | 2022-01-17 05:00:00 |
| 59TA3312 | Nissan | Skyline | 2022-01-17 04:00:00 |
| 59TA3312 | Nissan | Skyline | 2022-01-17 04:30:00 |
| 129EA512 | Subaru | Impreza | 2022-01-17 03:30:00 |

What i am trying to achieve is;

| Plate | Brand | Model | FirstPhotoDate | SecondPhotoDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99AA111 | Tesla | S | 2022-01-17 04:00:00 | 2022-01-17 04:30:00 |
| 99AA111 | Tesla | S | 2022-01-17 05:00:00 | - |
| 59TA3312 | Nissan | Skyline | 2022-01-17 04:00:00 | 2022-01-17 04:30:00 |
| 129EA512 | Subaru | Impreza | 2022-01-17 03:30:00 | - |

I have came up with;

```
var groupedResult = resultList.GroupBy(f => f.Plate).Select(f => new ResultListView
{
    Plate = f.Key,
    FirstDate = f.Min(f => f.InsertDate),
    SecondDate = f.Max(f => f.InsertDate),
    Brand = f.FirstOrDefault().Brand,
    Model = f.FirstOrDefault().Model,
    TimeDifference = (f.Max(f => f.InsertDate) - f.Min(f => f.InsertDate)).TotalMinutes
});
```

But as it's obvious in the code, it only gives me the first and the last record but not as  I expected. I am trying to group by plates and if same plate goes more than once, match it with the next one. if only there is one photo or three photo, second date should be null.

Of course different logic's could be applied but I believe this is more clear way.

**I thougt that looping inside grouped result. Take first and the second and skip two. But this is not I am looking for.**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about `FirstPhotoDate` and `SecondPhotoDate`? is it always closest timestamps?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention, that photos are ordered by the date. I am calculating time difference between first and the next picture.

Comment: Order f by insert date and take the first and the second element.

Comment: then group by plate number... order by date... take 1st and second... skip 2... take again 1st and 2nd... till there are records... seems like a very straightforward solution... maybe somebody suggests something better

Comment: @demo I actually thought that. Looping inside grouped results. Take first and the second and go skip next but I am looking for a result without doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, having (let use named tuple to demo):

```
var resultList = new (string Plate, string Brand, string Model, DateTime InsertDate)[] {
  ("99AA111",  "Tesla",  "S",       new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,00,00)),
  ("99AA111",  "Tesla",  "S",       new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,30,00)),
  ("99AA111",  "Tesla",  "S",       new DateTime(2022,01,17, 05,00,00)),
  ("59TA3312", "Nissan", "Skyline", new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,00,00)),
  ("59TA3312", "Nissan", "Skyline", new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,30,00)),
  ("129EA512", "Subaru", "Impreza", new DateTime(2022,01,17, 03,30,00)),
};
```

You can `GroupBy` *twice*:

```
var groupedResult = resultList
  .GroupBy(item => item.Plate)
  .SelectMany(group => group
     .OrderBy(item => item.InsertDate)
     .Select((item, index) => (item: item, index: index / 2))
     .GroupBy(pair => pair.index)
     .Select(g => (
        Plate: g.First().item.Plate,
        Brand: g.First().item.Brand,
        Model: g.First().item.Model,
        FirstPhotoDate: g.First().item.InsertDate,
        SecondPhotoDate: (g.Count() == 1 ? null : (DateTime?)(g.Last().item.InsertDate))
     ))
   );
```

Let's have a look:

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, groupedResult
  .Select(r => $"{r.Plate,-8} : {r.Brand,-6} : {r.Model,-7} : {r.FirstPhotoDate} : {r.SecondPhotoDate}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
99AA111  : Tesla  : S       : 17.01.2022 4:00:00 : 17.01.2022 4:30:00
99AA111  : Tesla  : S       : 17.01.2022 5:00:00 : 
59TA3312 : Nissan : Skyline : 17.01.2022 4:00:00 : 17.01.2022 4:30:00
129EA512 : Subaru : Impreza : 17.01.2022 3:30:00 :
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. Hope I can reach this level of experience one day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest approach I can think of:

```
var resultList = new (string Plate, string Brand, string Model, DateTime InsertDate)[]
{
    ("99AA111",  "Tesla",  "S",       new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,00,00)),
    ("99AA111",  "Tesla",  "S",       new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,30,00)),
    ("99AA111",  "Tesla",  "S",       new DateTime(2022,01,17, 05,00,00)),
    ("59TA3312", "Nissan", "Skyline", new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,00,00)),
    ("59TA3312", "Nissan", "Skyline", new DateTime(2022,01,17, 04,30,00)),
    ("129EA512", "Subaru", "Impreza", new DateTime(2022,01,17, 03,30,00)),
};

var query =
    from r in resultList
    group (DateTime?)r.InsertDate by new { r.Plate, r.Brand, r.Model } into grs
    from bgrs in grs.OrderBy(x => x).Buffer(2)
    select new
    {
        grs.Key.Plate,
        grs.Key.Brand,
        grs.Key.Model,
        FirstPhotoDate = bgrs.First(),
        SecondPhotoDate = bgrs.Skip(1).Any() ? bgrs.Last() : null,
    };
```

I used the `Buffer` operator from Microsoft's `System.Interactive` NuGet.

That gives me:

[image: query]